# Read value from XML node

Tags: xml, vb.net

Format of XML File

```
<Main>
    <Item>
         <ProductDescription ID="123" LongDescription="Text" Langid="1">
    </Item>
</Main>
```

And i am trying to get LongDescription value (Text) from the XML file

Code i use

```
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(path)
    Dim xNList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//Main/Item/ProductDescription")
    For Each xNode As XmlNode In xNList
        MsgBox(xNode.OuterXml)
    Next
```

Result i get is

```
<ProductDescription ID="123" LongDescription="Text" Langid="1">
```

But i just want the value Text thanks in advance

Sorry for typos

Comment: there is no velue in this xml. i think xml file should be like this:
`<Main>
    <Item>
         <ProductDescription ID="123" LongDescription="Text" Langid="1">the value</ProductDescription>
    </Item>
</Main>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the element in `xNode`. All you have to do is to access the attribute `LongDescription`. The easiest way is to cast `xNode` to `XmlElement` and use the [GetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7(v=vs.100).aspx)-method:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(path)
Dim xNList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//Main/Item/ProductDescription")
For Each xNode As XmlNode In xNList
    Dim longDesc = DirectCast(xNode, XmlElement).GetAttribute("LongDescription")
    MsgBox(longDesc)      
Next
```